# How to make a pixel perfect adjustable outlined circle in Photoshop and also Illustrator, like, the one that Microsoft Paint has, as example?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector, photoshop-scripting, pixel

How to make a pixel perfect adjustable outlined circle  (with a simple tool so the circle can be readjusted and newly calculated later) in Photoshop and also Illustrator, like, the one that Microsoft Paint has, as example?

Like in Photoshop, I could go and use the Eclipse selection tool, remove the "smoothing" and apply a stroke. However, if I resize the circle, the circle does not recalculate, it resizes it on how the circle is, the circle stays the same with the pixels, which is an issue.

This is how the one in Paint looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhY4F.png

In Paint I can use the tool easily without any problems.

And if I create a circle in Photoshop, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCjh4.png

So, yeah it's like all blurry and stuff.

The same thing goes in Illustrator, however I found this comment https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/pixel-circle-no-fade-no-fill-how-exactly-pixel-art/td-p/9627897#M143458

That says, that you can use the path of the circle and then apply a stroke by using the pencil tool, which makes it look correct, but I couldn't find a way to do that, not sure what exactly he was talking about. But if that would be possible to do, it would be a possible solution because the circle would then be correct and can be adjusted and copied at any time.

Or is there a Photoshop extension, script for that, that adds the tool aswell?

Comment: Its possible tu turn antialiasing off in illustrator

Comment: I'm not sure if I remember the option but in Photoshop and Illustrator I tried to turn it off and for some reason it's still there.

Comment: this is possible but no shortcuts seems to be available I guess! the fact is if you want this for large scale operation then you can try making a script which will read pixel data and will erase pixel with less than 50% of alpha or some sort of things like this